# Webgl 2 - некорректное отображение цвета при использовании альфа смешивания

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

Рисую много раз треугольник красного цвета с прозрачностью, шейдер максимально тупой

```
out vec4 Color;
void main(){
    Color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 0.01);
}
```

Использую смешивание

```
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Ожидал, что постепенно треугольник превратится в полностью красный
В реальности краснеющий треугольник после определенного числа отрисовок вдруг становится ярко-синим
[image: гифка]
Кстати, вот набросал пример этого недоразумения: https://jsfiddle.net/v8qrakj0/2/
Мне уже хочется плакать от этого вашего webgl
Что я сделал не так и как это лечится? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в браузере OperaGX, в Chrome и Firefox работает как надо.